# Grid area works without defined area / columns / rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

So I was working on a small project and I was able to complete it, too. At the end of the project, I noticed that the code shouldn't work but it was working:

```js
let size = 15; //fornow
const con = document.querySelector("#container");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    let box = document.createElement("div");
    box.style.cssText = `grid-area: ${i + 1}/${j + 1}/${i + 2}/${j + 2}`;
    box.classList.add("tile");
    con.appendChild(box);
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border: 4px rgb(216, 216, 216) solid;
  display: grid;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.tile {
  border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

A perfect square grid gets created when the size variable is given a value with all the divs arranged in rows and columns. This thing I didn't understand is that I just wrote a container to be `display: grid` and didn't even define any row-column or template or even any grid property. Even `grid: 'something'` is missing too.

How come my code works and all the child elements get perfectly arranged by just using grid area property where the max area isn't even defined?

I tried to search if there is any by default grid property, but even it requires you to write something starting with "grid".

Comment: Because your JS creates CSS for each tile of the grid `.tile { grid-area: ... }` [w3schools: CSS grid-area Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp).

Comment: @RenevanderLende yes but i havent defined the size and grid template/row/columns in the parent container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How come my code works and all the child elements get perfectly arranged by just using grid area property where the max area isn't even defined?*

You don't need to define any rows or columns ("tracks") on the container.

In the absence of author-defined ("explicit") tracks, the grid algorithm creates its own ("implicit") tracks to accommodate grid areas.

With your script, you are creating implicit grid lines.

[image]

As you can see in the CSS, the `grid-area` property is defining row and column lines. Because these lines don't match to any explicit tracks, implicit tracks are created.

From the spec:

> [§ 7.1. The Explicit Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)
>
> The three properties `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`,
> and `grid-template-areas` together define the **explicit grid** of a
> grid container.

But these properties don't exist in the code. So the JS ends up creating implicit lines.

> [§ 7.5. The Implicit
> Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids)
>
> The `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`, and
> `grid-template-areas` properties define a fixed number of tracks that
> form the explicit grid. When grid items are positioned outside of
> these bounds, the grid container generates **implicit grid tracks** by
> adding **implicit grid lines** to the grid.

---

The "perfect square" shape of the container is a result of its defined size (`50vh` x `50vh`).

```
#container {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border: 4px rgb(216, 216, 216) solid;
  display: grid;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```